# Is it possible to load a TikZ library locally?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzlibrary

Is it possible to load a TikZ library and make it local to a `tikzpicture`?

I'm writing a long document, and feel like the different TikZ libraries required for different diagrams are "littering" the namespace.

Comment: You can group it but I don't know if you gain much : `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}\begin{document}\begingroup\usetikzlibrary{calc}\tikz \draw(0,0) -- ($(1,1)+(2,2)$);\endgroup\tikz \draw(0,0) -- ($(1,1)+(2,2)$);\end{document}`

Answer (score 14):

Macro `\usetikzlibrary` is defined at the end of file `tikz.code.tex`. The macro remembers the state of a loaded module `<foo>` in the *global* macro `\tikz@library@<foo>@loaded`. If a module is loaded locally, all its local definitions and assignments are lost after the group, but `tikz` still thinks, the module is loaded and ignores further load requests (example taken from percusse's comment):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \tikz\draw(0,0) -- ($(1,1)+(2,2)$);
\endgroup
\begingroup
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \tikz\draw(0,0) -- ($(1,1)+(2,2)$);
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

The result is an error in the second `\tikz` statement in line 9:

```
! Package tikz Error: You need to say \usetikzlibrary{calc} for coordinate calculation.
```

Macro `\usetikzlibrary` can be patched to make the remembering of the load state local:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \patchcmd{\use@@tikzlibrary}{\global}{}{}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \tikz\draw(0,0) -- ($(1,1)+(2,2)$);
\endgroup
\begingroup
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \tikz\draw(0,0) -- ($(1,1)+(2,2)$);
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

This works for module `calc`, because its definitions (`tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex`) are local. But the global load marker shows that libraries are intended to be loaded at top level. There it does not matter, if a macro is defined locally or globally. Thus there might be modules with relevant global assignments that persist after the group and disturb further `tikz` code.

Answer (score 1):

A way to solve this problem would be to store the TikZ figures as standalone documents:

```
% file figures/myfigure.tikz
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}    
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % picture goes here
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the main file, include the generated pdf with `\includegraphics{figures/myfigure.pdf}`.

In order to let latexmk know that it should recompile the PDF files when they are outdated, add this to a `.latexmkrc`:

```
add_cus_dep( 'tikz', 'pdf', 0, 'tikz2pdf' );
sub tikz2pdf {
    $_[0] =~ m@^(.*/)([^/]+)$@;
    my ( $dir, $file ) = ($1,$2);
    system("pdflatex -output-directory $dir $_[0].tikz");
}
```

The latexmk part will only work if you don't include any other PDF files. If you do, you can probably solve it by using another extension for these.