# Beamer uncover decoration bug

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, decorations

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\frame{
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzstyle{kringel}=[decoration={random steps}]
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[black] (3,2.5) decorate [kringel] {-- (2,5)};
\end{tikzpicture}

%\uncover<2->{test}
}
\end{document}
```

Compiles without any problems. If I replace

```
%\uncover<2->{test}
```

with

```
\uncover<2->{test}
```

then it does not compile and gives the following error:

```
./test.tex:18: Package tikz Error: You need to load a decoration library.
```

If I move the two lines

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzstyle{kringel}=[decoration={random steps}]
```

into the document header, i.e., before

```
\begin{document}
```

then it compiles and works. Can someone explain to me what is happening here?

Comment: You must call `\usetikzlibrary` in your preamble.

Comment: Move the `usetikzlibrary` out and place before `\begin{document}`

Comment: @PaulGaborit This is what I found out. But do you have an explanation for why this problem only appears when I insert  this uncover command?

Comment: This is almost a duplicate (but not really so reviewers please don't vote) to this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111146/is-it-possible-to-load-a-tikz-library-locally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What it boils down to in the very end is that you probably shouldn't try to use `\usetikzlibrary` in a group.

With a bit of paring down, the error already occurs in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\endgroup

\tikzstyle{kringel}=[decoration={random steps}]
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[black] (3,2.5) decorate [kringel] {-- (2,5)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As soon as you have more than one overlay in a frame, as by using a `<2->`, the whole frame is parsed several times, throwing away the stuff that is not applicable to the current overlay. Every iteration is done in a group, to limit side effects seeping out. It now appears (I've not gone down that rabbithole) that `\usetikzlibrary` is clever enough to not load anything twice. So your library is loaded for overlay `<1>`, not loaded for overlay `<2>`, but its definitions aren't there because they weren't global.