# Is it possible to use \usetikzlibrary inside a figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf

It seems that whenever I use `\usetikzlibrary` in the context of `\begin{figure}`, the library is not loaded. I often put the content of my figures in separate files, and I'd like to place the library usage in the same file, but right now it seems I have to put `\usetikzlibrary` outsid the figure in another file. Is there any way to get the library to load from within a figure environment?

Comment: Why are you not loading it in the preamble of the main file?

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. It is quite possible that the loading of libraries is restricted to the preamble. Jusst like you cannot load packages within the document.

Comment: Does [Is it possible to load a TikZ library locally?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111146/13304) help?

Comment: It works in the body of the document, but not inside a figure environment. If putting it into the preamble is best practice, though, then that's what I'll do.

Comment: It is indeed the best practice.